# Can sshd be configured to support multiple connections when running standalone?

Tags: sshd

I'm trying to create an SSH server Docker image that can establish multiple concurrent connections:

- Server

```
> sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -Ddp 1234
```

- Client 1

```
> ssh user@server -p 1234
user@server's password:
...
```

- Client 2

```
> ssh user@server -p 1234
ssh: connect to host server port 1234: Connection refused
```

The same server machine which has an ssh-server daemon run by systemd *does* allow for multiple connections.

Is there a way to configure `sshd` to run standalone, ie. not with a service manager like systemd, or is `sshd` fundamentally only meant to handle a single connection and the concurrency comes from it being managed? If so, what is systemd doing to allow for concurrent connections if it's only told `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS` (doesn't look like `SSHD_OPTS` is being set anywhere)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `-d` gets in the way. From [`man 8 sshd`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd):

> `sshd` listens for connections from clients. […] It forks a new daemon for each incoming connection. […]

And later [emphasis mine]:

> `-d`
>   Debug mode. The server sends verbose debug output to standard error, and does not put itself in the background. **The server also will not fork and will only process one connection.** […]

My tests indicate `sshd -d` behaves like you described. When I run it without `-d` it is able to handle multiple connections just fine.

Comment: I think I must have added that to solve a previous issue and not realised it had created another, I'll double check I'm actually calling the same commands in future!

Answer (score 1):

Debugging sshd over multiple connections can be achieved using the following.

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 -De
```